# How can I keep all values of an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, local-storage

Here is my code:

**CSS:**

```
li{
  cursor: pointer;
}

 li:hover{
    background-color: #eee;
 }
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
  <li><a href='#1'>first post</a></li>
  <li><a href='#2'>second post</a></li>
  <li><a href='#3'>third post</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
var seen = [];
$('li').on('click', function(){
$(this).css('background-color','pink');
// storing into localstorage
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if(!seen.includes($(this).find('a').attr('href'))){
        seen.push($(this).find('a').attr('href'));
        // Set to localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('seen', JSON.stringify(seen));
    }
  }
});

var seenAlready = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('seen'));
$.each(seenAlready,function(index, value){
   $("a[href="+'"'+value+'"'+"]").parent().css('background-color','pink');
});
```

As you see in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7hww5116/), that pink color will be remine just for one element *(after reloading the page)*. Also as you know, that's because of this line:

```
var seen = [];
```

How can I handle this problem and keep all values of that array?

Comment: I'm a little confused on what issue you're having. I ran your JSFiddle and I clicked 2 links, refreshed the page, and they both were highlighted just fine.

Comment: Also for me is working

Comment: @James Odd ..! because it works totally different for me.

Comment: @rakwaht this ^ !

Comment: Could be some browser caching issues. Chrome is notorious for it.

Comment: Just clear cache/history/cookies/ecc. from your browser and try again

Comment: It doesn't work because it remembers only the links clicked on the previous page visit, not the ones before that (e.g. if you click on two links, reload, click on the third link, reload, it shows only the third link highlighted). You'll have to add `seen = seenAlready || [];` at the end to fix that (https://jsfiddle.net/7hww5116/5/).

Comment: Great. thank you @JJJ ..! why didn't you write an answer?